# I'm trying to delete a key value pair from shopping list

Tags: javascript, ide, flatiron.js

everyone. I am trying to write a function that takes an item, looks through a current shopping cart(an object), checks if the item is in the cart, deletes it if true, and return "That item is not in your cart." if false. I have this so far.

```
var cart = {}

function removeFromCart(item){
var cartItems = Object.keys(cart)
for (var i=0; i<cartItems.length ; i++){
  if (cartItems[i]===item){
    delete cart.item
    return
    }
  else if (i === cartItems.length)  {
    console.log("That item is not in your cart.")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can omit the "elfe-if" block and insert the " console.log("That item is not in your cart.")" after the for loop. Note: I am not saying this will solve your problem, just a suggestion. Also, always insert semi-colons.

Comment: what is the definition of `item`. Is it a string or an object?

Comment: figured it out!! thanks!